# Joins symfony 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have 3 tables and I use YAML, which is connect to each other like this:

Trainings:

```
oneToMany:
        exerciseTrainings:
            targetEntity: ExerciseTraining
            mappedBy: training
            cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
            joinColumn:
                name: id
                referencedColumnName: training_id
```

Exercises:

```
oneToMany:
    exerciseTrainings:
        targetEntity: ExerciseTraining
        mappedBy: exercise
        cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
        joinColumn:
            name: id
            referencedColumnName: exercise_id
```

trainingExercises:

```
manyToOne:
    exercise:
        targetEntity: Exercise
        inversedBy: exerciseTrainings
        joinColumn:
            name: exercise_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    training:
        targetEntity: Training
        inversedBy: exerciseTrainings
        joinColumn:
            name: training_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

[image: exerciseTraining table:]

I need "exercise name" from table Exercises(basically name coming from exercise_translation, but I think it's not a problem) that related to my Trainings and also I need "sets" from exerciseTrainings table. So I have training and try to join tables:

```
$training = $em->getRepository('TrenkaTrainingBundle:Training')->findOneByAlias($alias);

$exercises = $em
    ->getRepository('TrenkaTrainingBundle:Exercise')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->innerJoin('e.exerciseTrainings', 't')
    ->where('t.training_id = ' . $training->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

But I get this error:

> Class TrainingBundle\Entity\ExerciseTraining has no field or
>   association named training_id

Maybe someone has same structures and know how to make it work? Also how to presented values from 2-3 tables in TWIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't have *training_id* field in your **ExerciseTraining** entity so you can't use it in your where clause, in your **ExerciseTraining** entity you have *training* field so you can try something like this :

```
$exercises = $em
    ->getRepository('TrenkaTrainingBundle:Exercise')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->innerJoin('e.exerciseTrainings', 'et')
    ->where('et.training = :training')
    ->setParameter('training', $training)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it gets to 
Error: Expected end of string, got '�'

Comment: wow! thanks it's working. I get names in twig {% for exercise in exercises %} {{ exercise.name }} But how to get sets from exerciseTraining in twig?

Comment: What about `{{ exercise. exerciseTrainings }}` ?